# Create dependent dropdown in Yii2

Tags: yii2, dropdown

These are two active-form fields in Yii2.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'navigation_type')->dropdownList(['Module'=>'Module','Screen'=>'Screen']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'showInUrl')->dropdownList([0=>'No',1=>'Yes']) ?>
```

When I click `Screen`, the second field should be changed to `Yes`. When I click `Module`, it should be changed to `No`. I have to save only `0` or `1` to the db.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to bind the `change` event to the first drop-down using javascript/jquery like below. add the script on top of your view and provide the `id` to both the dropdowns.

```
$this->registerScript("
    $('#navigation_type').on('change',function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'Module'){
          $('#showInUrl').val(0);
       }else{
          $('#showInUrl').val(1);
       }
});",\yii\web\View::POS_END);

<?= $form->field($model, 'navigation_type')->dropdownList(['Module'=>'Module','Screen'=>'Screen'],['id'=>'navigation_type']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'showInUrl')->dropdownList([0=>'No',1=>'Yes'],['id'=>'showInUrl' ])?>
```

Apart from above solution, you should look into [DepDropDown by kartik](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) which reduces your efforts to 
a maximum and you just need to integrate and it works great.

Comment: will it store 0,1 for 'no', 'yes' in db?

Comment: you need to change the values for the `showInUrl` drop-down to `0` and `1` instead of `Yes` and `No` in order to do that @BeginnerDev i edited the script see now

Comment: i repaced `$('#showInUrl').val('No');` with `$('#showInUrl').val(0);` and `$('#showInUrl').val('Yes');` with `$('#showInUrl').val(1);` you can check now it whould work correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
Using Kartik/select Dropdown You Can Code like These : 

<div class="navigation-form">

<?= $form->field($model, 'navigation_type')
->widget(kartik\select2\Select2::className(), [
        'data' => ['Module'=>'Module','Screen'=>'Screen'],
        'options' => ['multiple' => false],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select Module',
                ],
        ])
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'showInUrl')->widget(kartik\select2\Select2::className(),[
            'data' => [0=>'No',1=>'Yes'],
            'options' => ['multiple' => false],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'placeholder' => 'ShoW URL',
            ],
]) ?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#navigation-navigation_type').on("change",function(e){
        var sel_val = $(this).select2("val");
        if(sel_val=='Screen'){
          $('[name="navigation[showInUrl]"]').val('Yes').trigger('change');
        }
        if(sel_val=='Module'){
            $('[name="navigation[showInUrl]"]').val('No').trigger('change');
        }
    });
```

Comment: For dependent drop-downs kartik has already a separate plugin that extends select2 http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop , what is the pont of using select2 instead of dependent-dropdown if you have to select the dropdowns manually in the end like a simple dropdown